# T-SQL code to add 7 days to a date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The below statement adds 7 days to the shipment date if we miss the ship date. For example, something that was supposed to ship on `07/24/2014` did not get shipped for some reason. The following query adds 7 days (resulting in `07/31/2014`) to the ship date.

The only problem is the 'Test Ship' column adds 7 days to the shipment date only on Sundays if we miss the shipment date. What I mean is that for the jobs that had a scheduled ship date of `07/24/2014`, and we missed shipping the jobs on that day, the below column 'Test Ship' updates the next scheduled ship day to `07/31/2014` only on SUNDAY.

For example, say job `J012345` did not get shipped on `07/24/2014`. Then the 'Test Ship' column will update the date to tomorrow i.e `07/27/2014` (Sunday) instead of updating it on FRIDAY `07/25/2014`. Am I missing anything here? How can I get 'Test Ship' to update the date on FRIDAY instead of SUNDAY?

```
'Test Ship' =
CASE
 WHEN j.JobStatus <> 'S'
 AND CAST(x.ExpectedDate AS date)
    < DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 3, CAST(GETDATE() AS date)), 3)
 THEN DATEADD(DAY, 4, CAST(DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week, 0, GETDATE()), -1) AS date)) 

 WHEN j.JobStatus ='S'
 THEN CAST(j.LastShippedDate AS date)

 ELSE CAST(x.ExpectedDate AS date)
END
```

Comment: please provide sample data and expected result

Answer (score 1):

See the solution posted at [SSC](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1596547-392-1.aspx), which can be summarised as:

1. Make the code easier to read by separating the `CASE` conditions.
2. Replace the non-deterministic function (`getdate()`) with a deterministic solution.

Comment: You're correct in noting that plagiarism isn't appropriate, but there is a middle ground of appropriate quoting and summarising in your own words. You can also apply the knowledge at a given link to the specifics of a question and give appropriate credit for it. (I can't speak for the voter, but prior to my edit most of your text was complaining about the site rather than answering).

Comment: @Flexo: The question above has been posted on multiple forums and the solution I referenced is exactly what is needed from my point of view. To apply the knowledge would mean to copy it. And my complaint about the website was after the downvote, not vice versa. Seems like this site is not a good place for me to participate...